# How to show points and polygons in single layer?

Tags: geoserver

I have big trouble to show points and polygons in same layer in geoserver.
I have one table named as ABC.
in ABC there are two geometry fields-
1.the_geom
2.the_geom_polygon

Note: Some rows may/may not have geometry values.

Now, I am trying to publish this on geoserver 2.2.

I created style like this.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd"
    xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld"
    xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>Testing</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Title>Point_polygon_style</Title>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
      <FeatureTypeName>Feature</FeatureTypeName>
      <SemanticTypeIdentifier>generic:geometry</SemanticTypeIdentifier>
      <SemanticTypeIdentifier>simple</SemanticTypeIdentifier>

<Rule>
<Name>polygon</Name>
    <MaxScaleDenominator>2500</MaxScaleDenominator>
    <PolygonSymbolizer>
    <Geometry><ogc:PropertyName>the_geom_polygon</ogc:PropertyName></Geometry>
        <Stroke>
              <CssParameter name="stroke">#FF8501</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-width">1.5</CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
  </PolygonSymbolizer>
</Rule>  

<Rule>
   <Name>poi_educational_institute</Name>
     <PointSymbolizer>
        <Geometry><ogc:PropertyName>the_geom</ogc:PropertyName></Geometry>
        <Graphic>
           <ExternalGraphic>
             <OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="test.png"/>
               <Format>image/png</Format>
           </ExternalGraphic>
           <!--<Size>
               <ogc:Literal>17</ogc:Literal>
           </Size>-->
       </Graphic>
     </PointSymbolizer>
</Rule>  

</FeatureTypeStyle>
</UserStyle>
</NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

When going to the Layer preview  , its showing Error like this

```
code="internalError"Rendering process failed
java.io.IOException
null
Error: Operation on two geometries with different SRIDs
```

I thing the values are null in the geometry fields(the_geom/the_geom_polygon).

How can i give filter to check whether geometry is null/not(in style)?

Can you please help me to solve this...

Regards
Mohammed Shafeek

Comment: I do not think the problem is null values.  I think you have existing values in an SRID that does not match the filter shape.

Comment: I checked the SRID , all are same.. (4030)

Comment: And the shape you query with- the SRID for the layer definition- is also of that SRID?

Comment: yes, this is my query **select srid(the_geom) from testing** , I am getting result like this [4030, ] -(after comma getting null because of null values)